# How to join conditionally with different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL.

I have three tables named `ratings`, `users` and one master table `master_entityType`.

Depending on the values from `entityTable` column of the `master_entityType` table, I have to join with another table. If the values from `master_entityType` is "Blogs", I have to join with `blogs` table. If the values from master_entityType is "items", I have to join with `items` table.

```
SELECT * FROM ratings AS r
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = r.userID
    LEFT JOIN master_entityType AS ms ON ms.entityTypeID = r.entityTypeID   
    CASE ms.entityTable
        WHEN 'Blogs' THEN INNER JOIN blogs AS b ON b.blogID = r.entityID
    END 
WHERE r.entityTypeID = '10' AND r.entityID = '1' AND r.userID = '1'
```

While using the above query I am getting error, please suggest some step to get that query to work.

Structure of the table are as follows,

In users table,

```
UserID  userName isActive 
 1       Dinesh    1
 2       Kumar     1
```

In ratings table,

```
ratingID   entityID  entityTypeID   userID  rating
  1           1          1            1       5
  2           4          2            1       4
```

In master_entityType table,

```
entityTypeID  entityTable  entityTypeName  entityTypeDescription  active
      1          blogs           Blogs             Null              1
      2          items           Items             Null              1
```

In Items table,

```
ItemID   name    collection     active
   4    pencil       12            1
   5     pen         06            1
```

In blogs table,

```
blogID   name     active
   1    socail      1
   2    private     1
```

Comment: Just use `LEFT JOIN`, but your attempt looks weird - *all* the rows returned by a query must be of the same type.

Comment: Give me SQL fiddle for table schema and some dummy data, I have done such kind on things in my project

Comment: what's the error you get? it's the main information to start from and you forgot to put it in the question... please add it to the question and don't drop it in the comments.

Comment: @Paolo I getting this error.                                                                                   Query : SELECT * FROM ratings as r  left Join users as u on u.userID = r.userID  left join master_entityType as ms on ms.entityTypeID = r.e...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case ms.entityTable
  when 'blogs' then inner join blogs as b on b.blogsID = r.e' at line 5

Comment: can you post the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Your design is strange, so performance is likely to be poor.

`UNION ALL` two tables together and join with the result. Something like this.
If MySQL has views, then create view that unions `Items` and `Blogs` table and use the view in other queries. It makes the queries easier to read, understand and maintain.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d117b/6/0). I adjusted the `WHERE` condition in the fiddle, because sample data doesn't have any rows with `entityTypeID = 10`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    ratings AS r
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = r.userID
    LEFT JOIN master_entityType AS ms ON ms.entityTypeID = r.entityTypeID
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            ItemID AS EntityID
            ,'Items' AS EntityTypeName
            ,name
            ,active
        FROM items

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            BlogID AS EntityID
            ,'Blogs' AS EntityTypeName
            ,name
            ,active
        FROM blogs
    ) AS Entities ON 
        Entities.EntityTypeName = ms.entityTypeName
        AND Entities.EntityID = r.entityID
WHERE r.entityTypeID = '10' AND r.entityID = '1' AND r.userID = '1'
```

Comment: Is there any ways to join the tables using case statements?

Comment: @Dineshkumar, I don't think it is possible to use `CASE` statement as you want. It simply doesn't work like this. `CASE` returns some value, such as `int` or `varchar`, it is not a flow control construct like `IF`.